# What is the difference between cached_property in Django vs. Python's functools?

Tags: python, django, python-3.8, python-3.9

Django has a decorator called [`cached_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) which can be imported from `django.utils.functional`. On the other hand, Python 3.8 added [`cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html?highlight=cached_property#functools.cached_property) to the standard library which can be imported from `functools`.

Are both equivalent, i.e., are they interchangeable? or what is the difference between both? Are there any best practices when to use one or the other?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some research both basically work the same way and the only difference you would see would be in the error handling and performance. There is a [ticket #30949](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30949) on Django's issue tracker to use `functools.cached_property` instead of `django.utils.functional.cached_property`.

You can see the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7cad0bee80a536c7e47f54cf43174175834f30a0/Lib/functools.py#L934-L981)  for `functools.cached_property` and also for [django's version [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f2ed2211c26ba375390cb76725c95ae970a0fd1d/django/utils/functional.py#L7-L49). The basic difference is functool's version does a little bit more error handling and the main difference is that functool (pre Python 3.12) uses locking mechanism for thread safety, this causes a performance dip compared to Django's version. From some [benchmarking](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30949#comment:9) done in the ticket linked above it seems Django's version is much more efficient in terms of performance:

> ```
> % python benchmark.py
> .....................
> Django Cache: Mean +- std dev: 12.8 ms +- 0.2 ms
> .....................
> Python Cache: Mean +- std dev: 113 ms +- 2 ms
> ```

There is also an [issue 43468](https://bugs.python.org/issue43468) on Python's bug tracker regarding this. Note that this locking behavior is removed in Python version 3.12 onwards and the performance should be mostly similar now.

In summary if you are using Python 3.12+ prefer functools version otherwise use Django's version if thread safety is not an issue otherwise you might want to use the functools version.